# Is there an easy formula to calculate this angle?

Tags: geometry

If $|AB|=|BC|=|CD|$ is there a (better not absurdly complicated) general formula for the angle $APD$ depending on the radius $r$ and $|AB|$?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arcs subtended by chords AB, BC and CD are all equal; cal the central angle in each of those arcs $\alpha$.  The arc DA subtends $2\pi - 3\alpha$.  Angle APD is given by half the distance between the arcs subtended by BC and AD, that is, 
$$
\angle APD = \frac{1}{2}( \alpha - (2\pi-3\alpha) = 2\alpha - \pi
$$

It is easy enough to find $\alpha$ from right triangle OAM where O is the center of the circle and M the midpoint of AB:
$$
\sin \left(\frac{1}{2}\alpha\right) = \frac{|AB|}{2r}
$$
Then 
$$
\angle APD =  2 \cdot 2\sin^{-1} \frac{|AB|}{2r} - \pi =  4\sin^{-1} \frac{|AB|}{2r} -  \pi
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $l=\left|AB\right|$. There are obvious limits where the angle is zero when $l=r\sqrt 2$ and if you want $P$ to stay outside the circle, then the angle is $60^\circ$ when $l=r\sqrt 3$. Some simple geometry shows the angle is
$$ \pi-4\cos^{-1}\frac{l}{2r} $$
radians.

Comment: Notice that both answers are equivalent because $\sin^{-1} = \pi/2 - \cos^{-1}$